# Object variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

i am new to oop concepts so please help me out here,
Whenever I am using an object variable the value stored in it is undefined.
Please check the below code

---

```
function Bubble(q, w, e) {
  var x= q;
  var y= w;
  var r = e;
  var canvas= document.getElementById('mycanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

var b1 = new Bubble(100,100,50);
var b2 = new Bubble(160,160,30);
alert(b1.x);
```

Comment: Please be more specific--which property of which variable is undefined?

Comment: specify your problem clearly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `var`. With `var` you create a scoped variable which is accessible in the `function scope`, with `this` you attach your variable to the current context. Refer to the `x, y, r` with the prefix `this.`.

```js
function Bubble(q,w,e)
{
   this.x = q;
   this.y = w;
   this.r = e;
   var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   ctx.stroke(); 
}

var b1 = new Bubble(100,100,50);
var b2 = new Bubble(160,160,30);
alert(b1.x);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the variable x until you add it as a property of bubble try using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), to access x outside. In your example x is a private variable and you won't be able to access it

```
function Bubble(q,w,e)
{
    this.x= q;
    this.y= w;
    this.r = e;
    this.canvas= document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
     }
   var b1 = new Bubble(100,100,50);
   var b2 = new Bubble(160,160,30);
   alert(b1.x);
```